# Retrieve input value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to retrieve the value of an input using jQuery.

Here's the HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="a" />
<input type="button" name="b" id="b" value="Click here"/>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var normal=$('#a').val();
    $('#b').on("click", function() {
            alert(normal);
  });

});
```

Due to some reason the `alert(normal);` does not work whereas `alert($('#a').val());` does. Why? Isn't `normal` and `$('#a').val();` holding the same value?

In case you want a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L2uX4/20/

Thanks

Comment: because it is not dynamic.... It does not rebind, the value you get at that point in time is what you have until you overwrite the variable again.

Answer (score 2):

if you declare `var normal` outside the click function handler then the initial value will be empty as there is no value in the text box once the DOM is ready . But if you declare it within the `click` event handler then the value will be assigned once you type something in the textbox and click the button.
The below code works for me

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    
    $('#b').on("click", function() {
          var normal= $('#a').val();
         alert(normal);
        // same as alert($('#a').val());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="a" id="a" />
<input type="button" name="b" id="b" value="Click here"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning `normal` upon `document.ready()` and not reassigning when you click, so normal will be whatever value you give to the input field when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        $('#b').on("click", function() {
        var normal=$('#a').val();
        alert(normal);
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right,

> provided the text box with `id= a` had some text on load.

by that I mean something along the lines of

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="a" value= "foo"/>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jayas/vhjm8v31/2/

Now if you hit `Clickhere` button it will display `foo`.

**In your case**

1. When you assign the value of  `a` to `normal` the text box is empty.
2. You dont have any handlers or events hooked up to reset/set the variable `normal`on something being typed or after something has got typed in. by that I mean something along the lines of having the value stored on `input change` along the lines of

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#a').bind('input propertychange', function() {
         normal = $('#a').val();
        }
    })
   ```

**Fiddle**  http://jsfiddle.net/Jayas/vhjm8v31/4/

> tl:dr - rebinding of the text to the declared variable does not "automagically" happen

So now  when you click on the button after reassigning `normal` you will see the typed value.

or alternatively you can capture the value of normal on click event as you already have it , along the lines of

```
  $('#b').on("click", function() {
        var normal = $('#a').val();
        alert(normal);
  });
```